# Logging missing values from dataframe into file with all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logging

I am trying to get missing values from dataframe to log into a file with the python program. I am using `logging` to output the missing values in `df`

```
if df.columnName.isnull().any():
    logging.warning('Following items missing for File > %s' + '\n' + str(
        df.loc[df['columnName'].isnull()].iloc[:, [1,2,3,4]]) + '\n', file_name)
```

The output is :

```
2015-01-01 10:00:53 AM: WARNING -> Following line items missing for File > X:/location/file_name.csv
     Date        ...   Qty
125  01/01/2015  ...   100

[1 rows x 4 columns]
```

There are other columns which not captured, truncated as `...`.

what I want is to show all columns not just `...`, since this hides all the information and reduces tractability.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html This might be useful

Comment: Need to adjust the number of columns and column width? [pandas options & settings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html)